# HTML how to upload a file to the server

Tags: javascript, html, replit

I want to upload a file to the server, so that another user can go onto the site, and search up the thing

It's going to take the file from the client, and put it into https://vidimax.elan1012549.repl.co/Videos/
or
Videos/

so ANY user can go in and see the video when the html retrieves the file
Videos/FILENAME.mp4

```
    <input type="file" id="VIDEO">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
```

then, on another page, any user can access it with the search bar in

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" autofocus id="SearchBar">
    <input type="submit" id="search" value="search" onclick="SetQuery(), GetQuery(), reload()">
    <br> <br> <br>
    <textarea id="ShowResultsFor"></textarea>
    <br><br><br>
    <div id="div">
      <video src="Videos/" width="1080" height="720" controls id="Result2">
      </video>
    </div>
```

```
let Query;
let Video;
function SetQuery(){
  var Search = document.getElementById("SearchBar");
  Query = Search.value;
}
function GetQuery(){
  document.getElementById("ShowResultsFor").value = ("Results for: " + Query);
  Video = (Query + ".mp4");

  document.getElementById("Result2").src = ("Videos/" + Video);
  console.log(document.getElementById("Result2").src)
}

function reload(){
    var container = document.getElementById("div");
    var content = container.innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML= content; 
    
   //this line is to watch the result in console , you can remove it later  
    console.log("Refreshed"); 
}
```

I specifically cannot use PHP because the browser just downloads the .php file, as it does not support php

and I wish for this to work on most browsers

edit: I found a method with python

Comment: This is for a video site, like YouTube, and I need a way for it to store the uploads

Comment: Javascript is a Client-Side language - This means that it runs on the end user's computer only. You will also need a Server-Side handler that would handle and store the upload.

Comment: This is far too broad a question... you need a server-side process to handle the file upload and storage. If your videos are under 5MB, you _might_ be able to use [Replit's database](https://docs.replit.com/hosting/database-faq) but you'll still need some server-side code

Comment: Is there any way to save it other than PHP, as PHP just downloads the .php file to the client's computer

Comment: the files other than the first one work, I just need an uploader

Comment: PHP is just one type of server-side language. Replit seems to support Python, Go and Node.js

Comment: it turns out repl needs you to subscribe to "hacker" to upload files from the website client to the server files